# how to get the cocos2dx's FrameLayout

Tags: java, cocos2d-x

In "Cocos2dxActivity.java", I see a "framelayout" variable in the "init" function

```
FrameLayout framelayout = new FrameLayout(this);

....

setContentView(framelayout);
```

but how can I get this variable!

Comment: Where you want and why?

Comment: a third sdk need this vavirable, and use this as a param to a function